# SQL Server LocalHost instance missing

Tags: sql-server

I have recently installed SQL Server Studio and the management tools.
However when I go to the management studio and click into the database engine there is no instance of a local host.

When I look at the local services there is no reference to the sqlserver service to start / stop or run.

How do I create the local host database engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) does not necessarily include a SqlServer installation. You will have to download a [free](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) (or paid) installation of SqlServer.